# Android. Facebook SDK friends list

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Using `FQL` I obtain a list of `ids`, `names` and `links to profile pictures` for all my friends. I place this information inside a `ListView`. I use `AsyncTask` to get the images and then I insert them inside an `ImageView` in each entry of the `ListView` alongside the name.

My question is: what should I do with the drawables I place inside the `ImageViews`? Keeping them in memory will for certain throw an `OutOfMemory` exception, as the list can get pretty long. Should I store them in a local cache? If so, what is the best way of doing it? Should I use `SharedPreferences` being that they are quicker? Or should I use `SQLite`? Or ...

What is the proper way of doing this?

P.S. I don't actually need code, just an explanation on the flow of it all.

Comment: ListView recycle views. I don't think you have to worry about the size of the list.

Comment: try storing the image in cache memory either in external or internal storage

Comment: You can use this library to asynchronously download and cache images https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: @Tarun Yes, indeed, but I still need to store the `drawables` somehow so when the `ListView` asks for a certain one I have it on hand and not re-request it. I'm guessing it's redundant to request the same profile pic every time the `ListView` needs it, no? So I should store them locally.

Comment: @Tarun ... hmm, looks pretty good. I'll take a gander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

The main features of the Universal ImageLoader for Android are:

```
• asynchronous loading and displaying images from the Internet or the SD-card;
• ability of caching loaded images in memory and / or the device's file system;
• ability to monitor the loading process by means of "listeners"
• effective working with the memory while caching images in the memory;
• wide opportunities to customize the tool to fit it to your needs.
```